# jQuery animating depending on the number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've been trying to write a function that shows or hides some things on click, and I'm currently stuck at showing/hiding depending on how many times the button was clicked. My code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#twitch-pasek-przycisk").click(function(){
                           var e=0;
                           e=e+1;
                           if(e%2==0)
                                 {
                                    $("#twitch-pasek").animate({left: '-150px'});
                                  }
                            $("#twitch-pasek").animate({left: '150px'});
                            var i=document.getElementById('licznik');
                             i.innerHTML = e;
                            });
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's jsfiddle I created showing my problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/tybin/pwjtg2c5/)
Shown value of variable e remains 1 despite adding 1 every single click. How should I construct it to make it work? Or perhabs there's some trick like the toggle() function, but for animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `e` variable outside the click event, otherwise it will be overwritten on every click and it will always return `1`. See the working snippet below:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var e = 0;
   $("#twitch-pasek-przycisk").click(function() {   
     e = e + 1;
     if (e % 2 == 0) {
       $("#twitch-pasek").animate({
         left: '-150px'
       });
     }
     $("#twitch-pasek").animate({
       left: '150px'
     });
     var i = document.getElementById('licznik');
     i.innerHTML = e;
   });
 });
```

```css
#twitch-pasek {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 0px 35px 35px 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  background: #2B2B2B;
}
#twitch-pasek-przycisk {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
}
#licznik {
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
#twitch-pasek-przycisk:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}
#twitch-kontener {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="twitch-pasek">
  <div id="twitch-kontener">
    Informations
  </div>



</div>
<br/>
<button id="twitch-pasek-przycisk"></button>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="licznik"> Counter: </span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. Honestly, I'm suprised I haven't figured this out earlier.

Comment: @JakubTybiński, You're welcome. Happy to help. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you click your in your click event `e` initializes to `0` every time
use this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          var e=0;
          $("#twitch-pasek-przycisk").click(function(){
                e=e+1;
                if(e%2==0)
                {
                   $("#twitch-pasek").animate({left: '-150px'});
                }
                $("#twitch-pasek").animate({left: '150px'});
                var i=document.getElementById('licznik');
                i.innerHTML = e;
           });
});
```